# Conditional loss based on second output

Tags: keras

I have a (composite) model that predicts 2 outputs. For `output1` I have a fixed `binary_crossentropy` loss. For `output2` I need a loss that goes like:

```
if output1 > 0.8:
    return binary_crossentropy(output2, output2_true)
else:
    return 0
```

How can I implement this logic for the loss in keras?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I think you need to write your own loss function, and merge the 2 NN using Concatenate(). Your conditional loss function could then be evaluated and propagated in 1 pass, based on the concatenated results of 1 and 2.
Maybe something like:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2662